# Terminal sometimes fails to find executables on local directory

Tags: command-line, path, profile

I can open my terminal emulator via a keyboard shortcut or through the apps finder that executes the `exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator` command. My terminal starts and I can `cd` to any directory and execute any binaries located on any `bin` directory on my system.

But whenever I launch it by right-clicking any directory on `thunar` and using the *Open terminal here* option it *sometimes* can't find any executable on my local binaries directory (`~/.local/bin/`). Simply put:

- Open terminal via app finder, command launcher, keyboard shortcut, … → It **can** find local executables.
- Open terminal via context menu on Thunar → It *sometimes* **can't** find local executables.

This happens on any terminal (`xfce4-terminal`, `xterm`, `gnome-terminal`). My machine is running Fedora 20 `XFCE` with `thunar` version 1.6.3-2.

I can't say for sure since when this started happening, because it has been some time, but this became more frequent in recent days. Also, I have to mention that once my terminals can find executables on my local `bin` directory and I add a new one, it won't find them again, until some time passes - no matter if it was launched via the `thunar`'s context menu or not.

Has anybody noticed this behaviour too? Can somebody shed some light on what's happening here?

Update:

I've noticed that my `.bash_profile` file is what adds my local bin directory to the `$PATH` environmental variable:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin
export PATH
```

And when I run a *login shell* (not started via the *context menu*), it executes `.bashrc` and then `.bash_profile`, so I proceeded to move those two lines from my `.bash_profile` to my `.bashrc` and now everything works fine.

So the question now is: why does the context menu command (which is the same as the *normal* command) somehow make my terminal to be launched as only *interactive* and not as a *login* terminal?

Comment: Have you checked the PATH variable has necessary bin paths ?

Comment: @Tingrammer Sorry I forgot to add that, yes, the `/home/user/.local/bin/` path is always present in the $PATH var.

Comment: @arielnmz - could you open your terminal via Thunar's context menu and then output here of the command `echo $PATH`? By default terminal opens in the home directory, so, for example, it probably would work if you put `./.local/bin` instead of `~/.local/bin`.

Comment: You should never use relative paths in your $PATH statement. commands and scripts can change the working directory. Also $HOME is safer then ~.

Comment: "So the question now is: why does the context menu command (which is the same as the normal command) somehow make my terminal to be launched as only interactive and not as a login terminal?" Add a new question for this.

Comment: Do you think this is a bug in thunar? I think I'd get more feedback if I file this as a bug instead of asking here, anyway, you answered my original question, thank you.

Comment: No I am pretty sure it's by design. But its a pretty big debate. When you open from thunar your already logged in. When you start the emulator by hand it emulates logging in.  It's been the center of a "right way/easy way" debate for a long time now.

Comment: No, a login shell does not load `.bash_profile`. You need to move the PATH setting to `.profile`. A setting in `.bashrc` will only ever take effect in terminals, never in GUI applications that aren't launched via a terminal.

Comment: @Gilles the *terminal that works* is launched via a command, the same command that is executed when I call the context menu's option, neither are called from within another terminal. And the bit about the `.bash_profile` being loaded on a login shell is what the man page for bash says, as stated in the other question referenced in the answer's comments, although I'll look more into moving the path statement to `.profile` as you suggest.

Comment: @arielnmz Sorry, I meant to write: a login shell does not load **.bashrc**. (Unless you added `. ~/.bashrc` to your `.bash_profile` or something like it.)

Comment: @Gilles now that makes more sense, my `.bash_profile` indeed loads my `.bashrc` but the strange part is that the `$PATH` env var isn't modified when I call the terminal from the context menu, which means that when thunar calls that command, my terminal only loads `.bashrc` and ignores `.bash_profile`, should thunar do that? I have to mention that this happens *most of the time*, about 7 out of 10 times I call the context menu option, but *not always*. It's strange.

Comment: @arielnmz That's the point: launching a terminal reads only `.bashrc`. If you put an environment variable definition in `.bashrc`, it only applies to that terminal and applications launched through it.

Comment: So if I launch a terminal that reads only `.bashrc` and I execute the `exo-open` command to launch another terminal within it, that *child* terminal will ignore `.bash_profile` too?

Comment: @arielnmz (Unrelated to this question). You recently asked about [how to find the name of a driver in the CUPS GUI](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144494/know-the-name-of-a-driver-to-use-on-the-cups-gui), but deleted the question. I'm guessing you deleted that because you found an answer somewhere. If so, I suggest you undelete it and post an answer. It's both allowed and encouraged to answer your own questions on the site. That'll help the next person facing the same question.

Comment: @derobert I closed it because it wasn't a real issue, the think is that I thought that the packages provided by my distro contained the drivers, however, I didn't notice the ones I needed weren't part of it, and I just had to download and install it. But I'll un-delete it as soon as I have a computer at hand. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say your running into a good old classic fight. To ~/.bashrc or to ~/.profile

Checke your $PATH in both.

Read and understand https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment It may answer your question.

Basically your logging in when your launch a terminal emulator, but not when you launch from thunar. This creates a different environment. There is no "right answer" to fix it, and it's a lot like vim or nano, but I usually just source a common file in ALL of them to setup my environments.

Comment: This is just a guess BTW but it seems right, please let us know what shell your using in each case, if this isn't it.

Comment: I'm really sure this has to do something with my issue, but the strange part is that I can launch a working terminal with this command: `exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator`, and the context menu option just launches the same command: `exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator --working-directory %f` (with that extra param). Is thunar doing some strange thing that somehow makes the *same* command launch a non-login shell?