# Know the name of a driver to use on the CUPS gui

Tags: cups, lpd

I have this *Epson L355* printer and according to [www.openprinting.org](http://www.openprinting.org/driver/epson-201207w/) I need to use the `epson-201207w` driver; however,  on the CUPS config panel at `http://localhost:631`, the list of drivers only displays names like *Epson E 300*, *Epson EM 900C*, etc, but not *Epson L355* nor even *Epson L300* is present on the list. I tried to investigate the "human-readable" form name of the said `epson-201207w` driver but I can't find anything. Is there a way to know, or at least guess it?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was missing the driver itself, I thought that the `gutenprint-cups` and `epson-inkjet-printer-escpr` packages would include said *driver* but they didn't (I'm against installing packages from the internet unless it's strictly necessary - this was one case - but that's why I didn't install it in the first time). The solution was to simply install the `epson-201207w` driver package from [www.openprinting.org](http://www.openprinting.org/driver/epson-201207w/).